# Mandrill inbound email

Tags: php, mandrill

I am trying to connect my mail server (bluehost) with mandrill to interpret inbound emails. I managed to add the MX records in bluehost, and created a domain where emails will be sent to and saved to the database.

The domain has been configured properly and file is able to save into database, and the route to the webhook is configured properly (as the 'Send test' via Mandrill works). However, when I send an email to the one associated with mandrill, it does not show up. Any clues where I may be going wrong?

P.s. I am using a PHP based routing endpoint and for simplicity, I am saving the contents in $_POST['mandrill_events'] to a MySQL database

Comment: did you check your outgoing mail server's logs to see what happens after PHP hands over the mail?

Comment: The strange thing is that if I use file_get_contents("php://input") instead of $_POST['mandrill_events'], it works <b>sometimes</b>

Comment: if you have content in php://input but not $_POST, then whatever you're sending is not being detected as a valid key:value set for PHP to stuff into $_POSt.

Comment: The value i get in php://input goes like this: mandrill_events=%5B%7B%22event%22%3A%22. Thus, I thought the key is mandrill_events. Regarding checking the server log, I am not too sure what you are referring to (i dont see anything useful in /var/log/maillog if that is what u mean)